# Cant Start a new React Native project

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I want to build a new App without Expo and without Yarn.

So I launched a new Projekt with react-native init and navigated inside the folder starting the Metro Server (works fine) - but when I want to start the android App on my emulator (AS Emulator) I get this Error:

```
    PS C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessApp\FitnessApp> npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 6 workers...
info JS server already running.
Der Befehl "adb" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.

> Task :app:installDebug
01:14:59 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
01:15:00 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:15:00 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_5X_API_29_x86(AVD) - 10' for app:debug
01:15:00 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'  
01:15:00 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
01:15:00 D/ddms: Reading file permision of C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessApp\FitnessApp\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
01:15:00 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
01:15:00 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:15:00 V/ddms: execute: returning
01:15:00 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
01:15:00 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:15:00 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
info Starting the app...
Der Befehl "adb" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
error Failed to start the app. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: adb shell am start -n com.fitnessapp/com.fitnessapp.MainActivity
    at makeError (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessApp\FitnessApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessApp\FitnessApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at tryLaunchAppOnDevice (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessApp\FitnessApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\tryLaunchAppOnDevice.js:57:22)
    at C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessApp\FitnessApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:104:39   
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessApp\FitnessApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:102:48)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessApp\FitnessApp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

I already tried to fix it but with no luck.

Before this error I had this Error:

```
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
```

My Project Android Folder is selected in AS and the Emulator is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error every time.

Follow this steps to get rid of it:

1) Open Android Studio.

2) Open your android folder of react native project in android studio.

*Now it'll start downloading all the necessary files*

3) Click on run button.

Now once application gets installed in your android device you can use `react-native-run-android`

Comment: I am already doing this - I did this again and also cleaned gradlew. Now my metro starts with node wich is fine. Still get the same error in vscode terminal tho

Comment: try running this command.
`react-native run-android --deviceId=emulator-5554`

Comment: It seems to work now - I started the App from the emulator and it worked dont know why

Comment: Yes, That is what i was asking before. :)

Comment: Tbh doing it like this sucks because i get the error everytime still is there a perma fix maybe?

Comment: Not at the moment but once i get will happy to update answer

Answer (score 0):

take the terminal goto your project folder using cd command and type npx jetify.

Comment: didnt fix it unforunatly

Comment: android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true, are these lines are present in your android->gradle.properties file?